# how can i get all the audio files in ionic 3?

Tags: cordova, ionic3

I want to create an audio player. I need to list all the audio files that are in all the phone directories

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, IonicPage} from 'ionic-angular';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
@IonicPage()
@Component({
selector: 'song-list',
  templateUrl: 'contact.html'
})
 export class SongListPage {

   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private file: File) {

 }

}
```